# Is it Possible to Construct a Dynamic Query Based on EF Metadata?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, ef-database-first

I'm trying to determine if the following is possible as a first step.

Essentially I would like to create a mechanism where from a field name (string) and value, I could dynamically find the field name in the metadata of an entity, and create a Linq query based on that information.

Assume that I only need to worry about a single table, and the columns on the table are all strings/varchars.

So, for example, if I have a table:

```
MyTable
----------------- 
Field1 
Field2 
Field3 
etc.
```

and this table has been generated in EF, I would be able to do something like the following:

var result = CreateDynamicQuery("Field3", "my value");

And I would be able to translate this into a EF/Linq query.

The reasons why this are needed are complicated, but a more conventional query mechanism won't work in this case.  What I am trying to avoid is a string-based SQL solution.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: not 100 percent sure exactly what you are asking, but I think LINQ Expressions Trees http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx may be used to solve your problem.

Comment: This looks promising.  Essentially I want to use this to query SQL via EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how to build a query with linq expression trees and entity framework to make a simple dynamic query:

```
public void TestEF()
    {
        using (DbContext db = new ElFaktura.Data.CustomerEntities())
        {
            var expr = CreateQuery<Customer>("FirstName", "Lorentz");
            var result = db.Set<Customer>().Where(expr);
            Debug.Print(result.ToString());
        }
    }

    public Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> CreateQuery<T>(string field, string value)
    {
        var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, field);
        var equalsExpr = Expression.Equal(propExpr, Expression.Constant(value));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer,bool>>(equalsExpr, paramExpr);
    }
```

the resulting sql is

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent1].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (N'Lorentz' = [Extent1].[FirstName])
```